# User and row level logging in MS Access 2010

Tags: security, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I recently developed an MS Access 2010 database and I want to add functionality that tracks the activity of each user. It occurs to me that I can create an `Activity` table and then add code to each form which adds a row to the Activity table whenever a user creates, views, edits, or deletes a record in the database.  But how do I do the following:

1. Identify a specific user:  Is there a User object so that calling something like User.getName() returns "JaneDoe" or "SallySmith" and I can thus store history for that specific user in the Activity table?  What is the syntax for retrieving the current user's username?
2. Lock down tables permanently so that only specified forms can create, modify, or delete records in specific tables.
3. Make sure that the Activity table cannot be edited by anyone other than one specific administrator account.

So that readers can better understand what I mean with the above three questions, the structure of the Activity table might include the following fields:

```
id  (primary key)
userName  (the name of the user who made the operation)
tableName  (the name of the table that was changed)
operation  (the type of change, such as create, edit, delete)
rowNumber  (the autonumber primary key of the changed field)
date  (the date the change was made)
```

I might add more extensive logging, but setting things up at this level would enable us to make sure everything works before getting more sophisticated.

I am interested to obtain answers to my above three questions. Links to more information in your answers would be very helpful.

Is anything like this already built into MS Access 2010?  Or do I have to roll my own?

Comment: It's not built in.  You have to roll your own.

Comment: @HansUp Thank you.  Any suggestions for the three primary questions?

Comment: If you decide to abandon the record view piece, and log only DML (add, update, delete) instead, search for Allen Browne app audit.  You may be able to build on what he provided.

Comment: @HansUp Thank you.  I did just google Allen Browne app audit.  Do your comments about the large amount of coding work also hold true if the database is stored at office365 online?

Comment: @HansUp To generate logs of record views, why can't I just put a simple `SQL INSERT` command in the `OnLoad` event of each form, sending the username, form name, and visible record(s) into the `Activity` table in the database? (Separately: I do not know about office 365 features; That's why I was asking.)

Comment: Here's an [interesting read](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/what-happened-to-user-level-security-HA010234561.aspx) for you - Access did indeed have user-level security at one point, but alas no more.  The funny part is that Microsoft never actually answers the question that is the title of the article, "What happened to user-level security?"

Comment: Is this a split database with the backend located on a network drive?  If so, will multiple users be accessing it at the same time?

Comment: @Blackhawk The security only becomes necessary if I make the database accessible via the internet, such as via office365.  I am trying to find out if there is a relatively simple way to upload my access 2010 application to the internet and then be able to track who views, edits, deletes each record.

Comment: @Blackhawk Yes, it is a split database. Perhaps 10 concurrent users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Username problem, you can use the Windows API function [GetUserNameW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724432%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
Public Declare Function GetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "GetUserNameW" (ByVal lpBuffer As Long, ByRef lpnSize As Long) As Long

Public Function GetWindowsUserName() As String
    Dim Bytes(0 To 511) As Byte
    Dim size As Long
    size = 256
    If GetUserName(VarPtr(Bytes(0)), size) = 0 Then
        'There was an Error calling the API function
    End If
    If size > 0 Then
        GetWindowsUserName = Mid(Bytes, 1, size)
    End If
End Function
```

If you want low level logging, I'd suggest that the best way of accomplishing it is to create a wrapper for the Recordset class that has all the same methods, but before calling the underlying Recordset members, performs whatever logging you want.  Unfortunately, I tested and was unable to use `Implements DAO.Recordset".  I received the error "Compile error: Bad interface for Implements: Interface is derived from another pure interface with non-restricted methods" - a new one for me :P

Comment: +1 for trying to help.  Thank you. Can you please show me explicit steps for how to call that from an event handler in access?  Like from the OnLoad event handler for a form called MyForm? I taught myself access and have only been using event methods up to this point.

Comment: Just put this into a module and call the GetWindowsUserName() function in the Event. It takes care of the low level stuff and returns a String which is the Windows Username of the current user.